# How to remove default example dags in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am a new user of Airbnb's open source workflow/datapipeline software [airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow). There are dozens of default example dags after the web UI is started.  I tried many ways to remove these dags, but I've failed to do so.

- `load_examples = False` is set in airflow.cfg.
- Folder lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags is removed.

States of those example dags are changed to gray after I removed the dags folder, but the items still occupy the web UI screen. And a new dag folder is specified in airflow.cfg as `dags_folder = /mnt/dag/1`. I checked this dag folder, nothing is there. It's really weird to me why it is so difficult to remove these examples.

Answer (score 180):

When you startup airflow, make sure you set:

`load_examples = False`

inside your `airflow.cfg`

If you have already started airflow with this not set to false, you can set it to false and run `airflow db reset`(if you are using 1.x `airflow resetdb`) in the cli (!which will destroy all current dag information!).

Alternatively you can go into the `airflow_db` and manually delete those entries from the `dag` table.

Comment: I've just tried this in 1.8.1 and it doesn't seem to be enough. I can confirm that the dag table is empty after running `airflow resetdb`, and I've made the change to the cfg file, but the example dags are all still there in the webserver. I had to restart the webserver to make this work. That involved killing a lot of processes and running `airflow webserver` again. Probably best to run with systemd or upstart to manage restarts https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/configuration.html?highlight=systemd#integration-with-systemd

Comment: running airflow resetdb command works fine in 1.10.5. 
should be accepted solution (upvoting for now)

Comment: This answer makes sense. The database is reset and uploaded with new data. I think OP forgot to check. @Bronzels

Comment: Since this is highly voted, people disabling example dags may also want to disable default connections. A similar property exists in 1.10.10 `load_default_connections = False` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407314/airflow-too-many-connections-as-a-default

Comment: Please note, this might cause your webserver to throw an error and won't load up. I had to recreate the user for the DAG to be up, and examples still are there. They didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Beware that resetdb will remove all the connections/variables that you have defined.

Comment: for the `airflow 2.0.1` , as I know; after setting `load_examples = False` inside your `airflow.cfg` use `airlow db reset` instead of `airflow resetdb`

Answer (score 54):

For Airflow 2.0,  in docker-compose.yaml you can set `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'` to not load them instead of editing the .cfg file.

Comment: This saved me a lot of banging my head against a wall. Thank you! The default docker-compose file in the documentation has this setting set and it overrides whatever is in the `airflow.cfg` file.

Comment: Everyone focused on the cfg file while the problem was with compose file, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Like others have said, you can change `load_examples = False` within `airflow.cfg`. However this requires that the cfg file already existing.

You can init the airflow DB without having to configure the cfg file by using ENV variables.

```
export AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
airflow initdb
```

See [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/set-config.html) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Before you start airflow make sure you set `load_example` variable to False in `airflow.cfg` file. By default it is set to True.

```
load_examples = False
```

If you have already started airflow, you have to manually delete example DAG from the airflow UI. Click on delete icon available on the right side of the DAG to delete it.

[image: Click on the delete icon available on the right side of the DAG to delete it]

Instead of manually deleting example DAG, you can reset your database by using `airflow resetdb` command but that will delete your connections and variables and other important information. Do not use `airflow resetdb` option in production.

Comment: the command is now `airflow db reset`

Answer (score 7):

**Easy Way:**

1. put ..

   load_examples = False

into the airflow.cfg file

2. then close and **restart** the webserver **and** scheduler

Comment: Restarting server `and` scheduler is the important part. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: check that you have *only* DAG files in your `dags_folder` -- Airflow will traverse this directory recursively and try to load all `.py` files.

I've lost some time debugging similar behaviour of Airflow: even though `load_examples = False`, airflow was still loading tons of unnecessary stuff, including example_dags. The problem was that I was having a virtualenv directory `venv/` in `dags_folder`, and -- I was not expecting that -- Airflow searches for dags *recursively* in the dags dir. So it was loading example_dags from the apache-airflow installed in that virtualenv.

UPD: there's a [`.airflowignore` file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#airflowignore) to ignore directories from `dags_folder`

Answer (score 1):

while starting up the airflow make sure to change

```
load_examples = False
```

in the `airflow.cfg` file .Then close and restart the webserver and scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, change the `load_examples` variable to `False` in `airflow.cfg`. Should look something like:

```
load_examples = False
```

If you have already started the server you need to reset the database.
In the newer versions, the command to reset the DB is:

```
airflow db reset
```

Some of the answers above use the old CLI commands

Answer (score 0):

If LDAP based authentication is turned on after airflow resetdb and restarting airflow your login window may not appear and may give an error due to cached login id ( but no password ).  If this happens, clear your cache and try.  If that still doesn't work, turn off authentication, stop airflow and start. Then turn on authentication stop and start - you will be able to see login window and login with your LDAP authentication
-Suresh