# Location of DAG's in Airflow when using CeleryExecutor

Tags: bigdata, workflow, airflow

I am new to using Apache Airflow, after going through the docs, I understood what type of executors are available in airflow and their basic working model.

My question is regarding the `CeleryExecutor`

When working with this executor, I am unable to find the find where will the DAG's reside.

My Airflow Config is as follows:

```
airflow_home = /home/airflow
dags_folder = /home/airflow/dags
```

When i run the command to list DAG's, I get the following output

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
example_bash_operator
example_branch_dop_operator_v3
example_branch_operator
example_http_operator
example_passing_params_via_test_command
example_python_operator
example_short_circuit_operator
example_skip_dag
example_subdag_operator
example_subdag_operator.section-1
example_subdag_operator.section-2
example_trigger_controller_dag
example_trigger_target_dag
example_xcom
latest_only
latest_only_with_trigger
test_utils
tutorial
```

Although, there is no `dags` folder present.

In my cluster, I am running

```
1 WebServer Node
1 Scheduler + Flower Node
1 MySQL Server Node
2 Celery Worker Nodes
```

It would be of great help, if someone can explain this concept.
To be more specific, I wanted to understand that `dags` folder will reside on which node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're listing the example DAGs that ship with Airflow. Look at the setting load_example in your configuration file airflow.cfg.

[How to remove default example dags in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410836/how-to-remove-default-example-dags-in-airflow)

For your cluster, you'll need to sync DAGs and configuration accross the different machines of the cluster. Look at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=cluster#multi-node-cluster and the Celery section

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that info. But maybe i wasn't clear, now that i can create my own DAG's. Which node will they reside in the cluster ?

Comment: You'll need to sync DAG and configuration accross the different machines of the cluster. Look at https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html and the Celery section

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please edit your answer to include the comment, I will mark it as the answer, maybe helpful as a direct answer for someone else.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks

Comment: Except it's 404'd now. Read the docs: https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#scaling-out-with-celery

Comment: Seems the right place is here now: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=cluster#multi-node-cluster