# Errno 13 Permission denied when Airflow tries to write to logs

Tags: logging, permissions, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We're running into a permission error when using Airflow, receiving the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler/2019-12-18/../../../../home
```

We've tried using chmod 777 -R on the /usr/local/airflow/logs/schedule directory within the container but this doesn't seem to have done the trick.

We have this piece in our entrypoint.sh script:

`export AIRFLOW__CORE__BASE_LOGS_FOLDER="/usr/local/airflow/logs`

Has anyone else run into this airflow log permission issue? Can't seem to find much about this one in particular online.

Answer (score 13):

Just for anyone with the same issue...

Surprisingly, I had to take a look to the [Airflow documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment)... and according to it:

> On **Linux**, the mounted volumes in container use the native Linux filesystem user/group permissions, so you have to make sure the container and host computer have matching file permissions.

```
mkdir ./dags ./logs ./plugins
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env
```

Once you have matched file permissions:

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
```

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. If you don't set AIFLOW_UID, all files will be created as root user which causes permission issues.

Answer (score 11):

Folder permission that is bind mounted could also result in this error.

For example:

docker-compose.yml (pseudo code)

```
   service_name:
     ...
     volumes:
      - /home/user/airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

Grant permission to the local folder, so that airflow container can write logs, create directory if needed etc.,

```
 sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx /home/user/airflow_logs
```

Comment: I had the same issue and I have solved it with the command: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/airflow_logs

Also, it is important to mention that this can be applied to any folder one is trying to export from container.

Answer (score 9):

I solved the issue: in my case the problem was that the volume mounted folders, `logs` and `dags` didn't have write permission. I added it with

```
chmod -R 777 dags/
chmod -R 777 logs/
```

and in the docker-composer file they are mounted as

```
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/bitnami/airflow/logs
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler'
```

The reason I got that error is because I didn't create the initial 3 folders (dags, logs, plugins) before running airflow docker container. So docker seems to have created then automatically but the permissions were wrong.

Steps to fix:

1. Stop current container

```
docker-compose down --volumes --remove-orphans
```

2. Delete folders dags, logs, plugins
3. Just in case Destroy the images and volumes already created (in Docker Desktop)
4. Create folders again from command line

```
mkdir logs dags plugins
```

5. run airflow docker again

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem using Apache Airflow 1.10.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 135, in _run_file_processor
    set_context(log, file_path)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 198, in set_context
    handler.set_context(value)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 65, in set_context
    local_loc = self._init_file(filename)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 148, in _init_file
    os.makedirs(directory)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 5 more times]
  File "/home/radifar/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/radifar/radifar-dsl/Workflow/Airflow/airflow-home/logs/scheduler/2020-01-04/../../../../../../../home'
```

After checking how file_processor_handler.py works I find that the error was caused by the different directory location of example dag and our dag folder settings. In my case 7 folder above the folder 2020-01-04 is /media/radifar. In your case 4 folder above the folder 2019-12-18 is /usr/local. That's why the PermissionError was raised.

I was able to solve this problem by cleaning the AIRFLOW_HOME folder then run `airflow version`, [set the load_example to False in airflow.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410836/how-to-remove-default-example-dags-in-airflow). Then run `airflow initdb`. After that I can use airflow without error.

Comment: For me load_examples = False was enough to fix the problem.

Comment: Turning off examples also resolved the error for me.

Comment: I have set `load_examples = False` but I am still getting Permission denied error. `airflow inidb` and airflow UI everything worked perfectly till yesterday but today I am getting this error. Can someone please help.

Comment: @alex yes solved it. For me it was related to permission issues. I changed the permissions to 777 and that helped me. What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: ok interesting - so you changed permissions for /scheduler logs folder? I posted here my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510335/airflow-on-kubernetes-errno-13-permission-denied-opt-airflow-logs-schedule this is airflow running on kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem running an Airflow image on docker hosted by Windows.

My solution was to override the CMD in the scheduler's dockerfile with a CMD that set the file permissions, before launching the default CMD.

The default CMD can be obtained with `docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Cmd}}' <schedulerImageId>`.

Example. I used the bitnami image ( docker.io/bitnami/airflow-scheduler:2.1.4-debian-10-r16 ). Inspecting the image I saw that the default CMD was

```
/opt/bitnami/scripts/airflow-scheduler/run.sh
```

So I created a `run.sh` script with the following content:

```
#! /bin/bash

chmod -R 777 /opt/bitnami/airflow/logs/
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/airflow-scheduler/run.sh
```

Then I added the following lines at the end of my dockerfile:

```
COPY run.sh /
RUN  chmod +x /run.sh

CMD /run.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but you could add a user to the default group, which creates the directory.

When your docker-compose is up you could run service `docker-compose exec SERVICE_NAME bash` and check to which group specific directory belongs to and then add this group to your user permission in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
service_name:
     ...
     user: USER_NAME:USER_GROUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to copy the files into the image whilst also changing the ownership.

```
COPY --chown=airflow . .
```