# Airflow avoid example DAGs

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I'm running a local instance of Airflow on my Mac. When the server starts, the scheduler successfully detects my DAGs, and they appear within the web interface. However, after a while, the example DAGs also start to show up despite having set the load_examples flag to False in the airflow.cfg file.

```
airflow config get-value core load_examples 
False
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this issue.

The way I start the server and scheduler are:

```
 airflow db reset
 airflow db init
 airflow webserver -p 8080
 airflow scheduler
```

Comment: please go over this thread that suggests the possible things to try for this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410836/how-to-remove-default-example-dags-in-airflow